# Singularity parallelism query

Tags: linux, docker, shell, containers, singularity-container

I am new to Singularity and container-based software, I am trying to inquire if it's possible to use singularity in a parallel fashion? In a dummy example, for instance, I have a shell script with command as follow:

```
# using parallel to spawn multiple processes
parallel -j 20 singularity run image.sif [some command]

# or just use &
for i in {1..20}
do
singularity run image.sif [some command] &
done
```

Is it going to create confliction when calling the same image concurrently?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, shouldn't be any issues on the singularity. Do be aware that they will share the same working directory though, and filename collisions are still possible.